# Facebook login from activity fails?

Tags: android, facebook

I have a custom button in an activity that I am using to allow users to log in via Facebook. My code for on click looks like this:

```
    CallbackManager callback = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("email","public_profile");
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this,permissions);
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callback, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            setUserLoggedIn(PrefUtils.Values.LOG_IN_METHOD_FACEBOOK);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // todo: something
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Logger.d("TAG",error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

However, the FB login dialog does not show up. Instead, I end up with an error dialog that asks me to login. I was assuming that this would start the dialog that shows the username and password edit texts.

How do I get that login dialog?

Comment: which error message is there on dialog can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Ajinkya `You are not logged in: Please login and try again`

Comment: have you declared facebookactivity in manifest also in onActivityResult have you called callback.onActivityResult...

Comment: Try replacing `this` (its the onClickListener anonymous class here) with activity context.

Comment: post you code and manifest file

Comment: @BajiraoShinde What's to post? There's a button with `onClick` listener. The code of the listener is in the question

Comment: have you initialize facebook sdk and have you added facebook activity in manifest ??

Comment: again i'm saying plz post your full code so we will come to knw where you are going wrong ....

Comment: @BajiraoShinde Okay, what part do you need ?

Comment: want to see declaration of callback manager

Comment: @BajiraoShinde `CallbackManager callback = CallbackManager.Factory.create();` This is the first line of the code I posted

Comment: have you initialise facebook sdk before it ??

Comment: @BajiraoShinde in `onCreate()` itself

Comment: well, i'm gonna post my code so check it...

Comment: @BajiraoShinde Sure thing. Just a heads up : this button is a custom button in an `Activity` :)

Comment: okz..that shudent be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, there is a little step that the docs fail to mention. Once you are done calculating the hash from debug keystore, you have to click on "Add Platform" in your developer profile and then select "Android" and follow the on-screen instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom fb button on click to open fb_login dialog

```
fb_login_button.performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

put this on button click onClick() method

```
Fblogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


               LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(context,

            Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));
    }
});



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this,permissions);   with  in button click

Answer (score 0):

Make your callback as a global variable i.e. initialize it below your

```
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Also override OnActivityForResult method of your activity and add callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data) as follows.

```
         @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Hope this helps. If it doesnt let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Do this steps

1. declare this variable at start

   public CallbackManager callbackManager;
2. call bellow function

   private void initializeFacebookSdk() {

   ```
       FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
       callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
   }
   ```
3. call this function on your button click

   protected void connectToFacebook() {

   ```
       LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "user_friends", "public_profile", "user_birthday"));
       LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
               // App code
               GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {

                       Log.v("FaceBook Response :", response.toString());
                   }
               });
               Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
               parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name,gender, birthday,email,link,picture");
               request.setParameters(parameters);
               request.executeAsync();
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancel() {
               Log.v("LoginActivity", "cancel");
           }

           @Override
           public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
               Utils.showToast(mActivity, "" + exception);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: This works for you when using a custom button in `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: I never doubted your honesty haha ! It's just a hassle getting this to work

Comment: Could this be a problem with a faulty hash of the keystore or something ?

Comment: Okay, try this, add [`flow`](https://github.com/square/flow) lib and see if ti causes an issue in your case. Heads up : you'll need to add some boilderplate

Comment: what that lib does ??

Comment: View switching. Anyways, see my answer :) I found the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am sharing my working code. Hope it will help you.

Inside your application class oncreate

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Then put facebook LoginButton in your layout and set its visibility to gone.
Then in the onclick of the custom button write this code:

```
btnFBLogin.performClick(); //btnFBLogin is the Facebook LoginButton.
```

Dont forget to add this after initialising LoginButton

```
btnLoginFB.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday"));
```

And in the oncreate call this function after initialising callbackmanager.

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
registerfb_callback();
```

Here is the registerfb_callback() function

```
 /*Registering fb callback*/
private void registerfb_callback(){

    btnLoginFB.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            showProgressDialog(); //Show dialog as your wish

            String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
            Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

        //Here I am logging out after completing the call.
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

                    progressDialog.hide();

                    try {
                        if(object != null) {

                            System.out.println("GraphResponse" + response.toString());
                            System.out.println("JSONObjectResponse" + object.toString());
                            Log.i("Activity", response.toString());

                            // Get facebook data from login
                            Bundle bFacebookData = getFacebookData(object);



                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){                     
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email,gender, birthday, location"); // Parámetros que pedimos a facebook
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            System.out.println("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"Network Error! Please try again!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            System.out.println("onError"+exception.toString());
        }


    });

}
```

Getting parsed data from JSON Object

```
/*Parsing facebook data from JSON Object*/
private Bundle getFacebookData(JSONObject object) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    try {

        String id = object.getString("id");

        try {
            URL profile_pic = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?width=200&height=150");
            Log.i("profile_pic", profile_pic + "");
            bundle.putString("profile_pic", profile_pic.toString());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        bundle.putString("idFacebook", id);
        if (object.has("first_name"))
            bundle.putString("first_name", object.getString("first_name"));
        if (object.has("last_name"))
            bundle.putString("last_name", object.getString("last_name"));
        if (object.has("email"))
            bundle.putString("email", object.getString("email"));
        if (object.has("gender"))
            bundle.putString("gender", object.getString("gender"));
        if (object.has("birthday"))
            bundle.putString("birthday", object.getString("birthday"));
        if (object.has("location"))
            bundle.putString("location", object.getJSONObject("location").getString("name"));

        return bundle;
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bundle;
}
```

And finally onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Hope it will help :)